# Simple load balancer doesn't work properly

Tags: go

I took loadbalancer code from google io 2010 and added implementation for priority queue and sync locking for Balancer. I intentionally set `workFn` function delay greater than for `requester` so I can see how pending value will be increased. I ran it in cli and noticed that after all workers start, program stops with pending value **1** for all workers and shows nothing. Where is mistake I cannot figure out, some times `completed` called only once or two times. It looks like `<-b.done` is not properly handled in select case.

```
package main

import (
    "container/heap"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var nWorker int32 = 6

func main() {
    rchanel := make(chan Request)
    workers := Pool{
        {make(chan Request), 0, 0},
        {make(chan Request), 0, 1},
        {make(chan Request), 0, 2},
        {make(chan Request), 0, 3},
        {make(chan Request), 0, 4},
        {make(chan Request), 0, 5},
    }
    doneChan := make(chan *Worker)
    balancer := Balancer{workers, sync.Mutex{}, doneChan}
    for _, elem := range workers {
        go elem.work(doneChan)
    }
    go balancer.balance(rchanel)
    go requester(rchanel)

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}

type Request struct {
    fn func() int
    c  chan int
}

func requester(work chan Request) {
    c := make(chan int)
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Int31n(nWorker)) * 2e4)
        work <- Request{workFn, c}
        go func() {
            result := <-c
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Done: %v \n", result)
        }()
    }
}

func workFn() int {
    val := rand.Int31n(nWorker)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(val) * 2e8)
    return int(val)
}

type Worker struct {
    requests chan Request
    pending  int
    index    int
}

func (w *Worker) work(done chan *Worker) {
    for {
        req := <-w.requests
        req.c <- req.fn()
        done <- w
    }
}

type Pool []*Worker

func (p Pool) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return p[i].pending < p[j].pending
}
func (p Pool) Swap(i, j int) {
    p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]
    p[i].index = i
    p[j].index = j
}
func (p Pool) Len() int { return len(p) }
func (p *Pool) Push(x interface{}) {
    n := len(*p)
    worker := x.(*Worker)
    worker.index = n
    *p = append(*p, worker)
}
func (p *Pool) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *p
    n := len(old)
    item := old[n-1]
    item.index = -1
    *p = old[0 : n-1]
    return item
}

type Balancer struct {
    pool Pool
    mu   sync.Mutex
    done chan *Worker
}

func (b *Balancer) dispatch(req Request) {
    b.mu.Lock()
    w := heap.Pop(&b.pool).(*Worker)
    w.requests <- req
    w.pending++
    heap.Push(&b.pool, w)
    b.mu.Unlock()
}
func (b *Balancer) completed(w *Worker) {
    b.mu.Lock()
    w.pending--
    heap.Remove(&b.pool, w.index)
    heap.Push(&b.pool, w)
    b.mu.Unlock()
}

func (b *Balancer) balance(work chan Request) {
    for {
        select {
        case req := <-work:
            b.dispatch(req)
            b.printStatus()
        case w := <-b.done:
            b.completed(w)
            b.printStatus()
        }
    }
}

func (b *Balancer) printStatus() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Status: %v %v %v %v %v %v\n", b.pool[0].pending, b.pool[1].pending, b.pool[2].pending, b.pool[3].pending, b.pool[4].pending, b.pool[5].pending)
}
```

Comment: Just to note, this code will leak goroutines on `Worker.work`. First observation. Still reviewing the code looking for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `balance()` goroutine eventually gets blocked in `dispatch()` on `w.requests <- req` at the same time that specific `Worker` is blocking in `work()` on `done <- w`, producing a deadlock for the goroutine running `balance()`.

Here is the fix you need. `balance()` needs to utilize goroutines internally. This will fix the issue because now it doesn't matter if the routine blocks in `dispatch()` or `completed()`, the main routine for `balance()` will continue `select`ing from the `channel`s.

NOTE: This does not work on the playground because it goes on forever.

```
func (b *Balancer) balance(work chan Request) {
    for {
        select {
        case req := <-work:
            go func() {
                b.dispatch(req)
                b.printStatus()
            }()
        case w := <-b.done:
            go func() {
                b.completed(w)
                b.printStatus()
            }()
        }
    }
}
```

Now that `printStatus` calls can be done concurrently, it needs to make use of the `mutex` as well, or you will get random `panic`s.

```
func (b *Balancer) printStatus() {
    b.mu.Lock()
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Status: %v %v %v %v %v %v\n", b.pool[0].pending, b.pool[1].pending, b.pool[2].pending, b.pool[3].pending, b.pool[4].pending, b.pool[5].pending)
    b.mu.Unlock()
}
```

Now if I could just figure out why the `pending` values just keep increasing... As far as I can tell, `Worker.work()` should only ever allow `pending` to be `0` or `1` because the `Worker` has to wait on `done <- w` before it can get another `Request` from `dispatch()`. I believe this is the desired result though isn't it?

Comment: Hi @RayfenWindspear, thanks for explanation, yes increasing of pending requests was done intentionally. But I still cannot understand why we get blocked inside `dispatch`, it is totally different channels, `done <- w` and `w.requests <- req`, and `select` wont be executed one more time while dispatch is in action, am I right?

Comment: @MaksymVolodin Right, with only one routine running it blocks waiting for that specific worker to retrieve the `Request` while the worker is blocked trying to `done <- w`. I'm actually not sure this is a very good example because it is very difficult to track down what is going on with so many channels involved and interacting in unintuitive ways. I've not had to look at a channel only to have to check the definition of it over and over again to see what exactly it's doing so many times. A tough piece of code indeed. Doesn't mean it isn't correct though.